# Unity3D WebPlayer WebService SecurityException: No valid crossdomain policy available to allow access

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-game-engine

**With Unity3D get WebService data:**

```
string str = "http://127.0.0.1:10081/dac/?room=401";
WWW www = new WWW(str);
yield return www;
```

**The WebService `http://127.0.0.1:10081/crossdomain.xml` must return the file:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse,
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "crossdomain.xml",
           Method = "GET")]
string crossdomain();

string IWCFContract.crossdomain()
{
    return "<?xml version='1.0'?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=* to-ports=* /></cross-domain-policy>";
}
```

But I got the following error:*SecurityException: No valid crossdomain policy available to allow access*, because the WebService returns "...".
How to get rid of the double quotes?
When I use socket, I can use `sockpol.cs` to solve this, but using WebService, it doesn't work.

Comment: Side note: Your XML string does not look valid... should have quotes around attribute values : `"domain=\"*\" ...`

Comment: But it will return **"<?xml version='1.0'?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=* to-ports=* \/><\/cross-domain-policy>"** The double quotes also return.The \ will return too if I did as you said.

Comment: I'm not sure why do you want to return invalid XML, but it is your call... Consider asking separate question like "how to return plain text string from WCF web service". Note that ASP.Net /ASP.Net MVC would be significantly easier to use to return whatever text/file you want - consider just going ASP.Net instead of WCF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity3d has a lot of protection, especially on web builds.

You need to provide a 'crossdomain.xml' file.

The essence of this protection is to prevent you from using someone's computer maliciously when they play your game.

[Unity's explanation of the problem and solution](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html)

Your crossdomain.xml should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="mywebsite.com"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="www.mywebsite.com"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="localhost.mywebsite.com"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="localhost"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: I know it.But how can I put the crossdomain.xml file on "http://127.0.0.1:10081/crossdomain.xml ? It's just a WebService,not a http server.

Comment: +1. @Gank - this is answer to your question as it stands now. Most of the question (and especially title) is about how crossdomain.xml should look like. You probably should either ask new question (and completely ignore Unity3d part) or rewrite this one...

Answer (score -2):

```
    namespace WCF.HTTP.Unity3d
{
    public class WCFService : IWCFContract
    {
        DataCfg m_dataCfg             = new DataCfg();

        Stream SetContext(string str)
        {
            OutgoingWebResponseContext context = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
            context.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.CacheControl, "public");
            context.ContentType = "text/plain";
            //    context.LastModified = date_image_was_stored_in_database;
            context.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str));
        }

        Stream IWCFContract.GetRoom(String roomName)
        {
            Loger.Instance.Info("IWCFContract.GetRoom:"+roomName);
            Data_Room data_room = m_dataCfg.ReadXml(roomName);
            string sJson = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToJson(data_room);
            return SetContext(sJson);
        }
        Stream IWCFContract.crossdomain()
        {
            return SetContext("<?xml version='1.0'?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" /></cross-domain-policy>");
        }
```

and another cs file:

```
namespace WCF.HTTP.Unity3d
{


    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWCFContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   UriTemplate = "crossdomain.xml",
                   Method = "GET")]
        Stream crossdomain();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   UriTemplate = "/dac/room={room}",//&index={index}
                   Method = "GET")]
        Stream GetRoom(String room);
```

I solve it by this. The WebService can return datas now.